# How to most efficiently load objects from Android SQLite database and sequentially upload them to a remote instance

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

#### Basis situation:

In my Android app, I am gathering large amounts of different data in multiple SQLite tables. Later, these tables are uploaded to a CouchDB server - Each table as a new database, each row of the table as separate document. I know it is bad style to simply transfer the design of a relational database one-on-one to a document-based one, however, this point shall not bother us right now :)

#### Problem space:

My problem is that some tables consist of more than 5000 rows. In my current code, I simply iterate over all tables and for each table over all its rows. For each row I then extract the data to the corresponding object A and bundle it up to the desired CouchDB document structure, i.e., a document with the fields `"_rev":String`, `"_id":String`, and `"NAME_OF_OBJECT_A":JSONObject`.

Next, an AsyncTask is started to bundle up such an uploadable object (in my code of type `CouchDBDocument`) to JSON and then upload it into the corresponding and already existing CouchDB database.

```
private void uploadNewSQLiteEntries() {
    // Iterate over all tables that have to be uploaded 
    for (AbstractDataSource dataSource : DataSourceHandler.getInstance(mContext).getAllUploadableDataSources()) {           

        // For each table, sequentially extract each row and transfrom it into the respective object
        for (AbstractLoggedObject object : dataSource.getEntriesCreatedSince(lastUploadTime())) {
            try {
                // Bundle it up into the upload format and start async upload thread
                String jsonBody = (new Gson()).toJson(object.encrypt(mContext));
                CouchDBDocument uploadDocument = new CouchDBDocument(object.getId(), uploadDatabaseName(dataSource.getTableName()), mBasisUrl, jsonBody);
                (new AsyncUploadTask()).execute(uploadDocument);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


private class AsyncUploadTask extends AsyncTask<CouchDBDocument, String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(CouchDBDocument... params) {
        CouchDBDocument uploadDocument = params[0];
        String jsonUploadDocument = (new Gson()).toJson(uploadDocument);

        // Executes an HTTP PUT at the specified url and with the specified json document
        return putJSON(jsonUploadDocument, uploadDocument.getBasisUrl()+"/"+uploadDocument.getDatabaseName()+"/"+uploadDocument.getId());
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        if (success) {
            Log.e("CouchDBUploadHandler", "Upload finished with success=true");
        } else {
            Log.e("CouchDBUploadHandler", "Upload failed");
        }
    }
}
```

#### My questions

Due to the high amount of data and the execution of multiple AsyncTasks at a time I am afraid that my app might eventually run out of memory in some cases. So to get to my actual question, how would you solve this?

- Is there a elegant and straight-forward approach for starting only one async task at a time?
- And how about the handling of the objects. Right now, my objects to be uploaded are stored into an ArrayList all at once and than step by step transformed and updated. If a table consists of 5000 rows this does not only take time but also eats a lot of memory. 
  Is there an easier solution, even loading only one object from the SQLite table into memory at a time?

Comment: AsyncTasks are anyway executed sequentially you might as well use a single AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using multiple threading style by queue:

1)put all objects that you want to upload in a blocking queue(java safe thread).

2)you have two stuff : one that reads from db and put your object in queue and one that reads from queue and
sends your object to a thread. that is one network dispatcher with configurable thread pool size.

you can also put another level if you are populating queue faster than dequeuing them by another thread to read from queue and store it on the disk and make network dispatcher use disk memory.

In this way you surely have a full controle over all your staff and threads and can configure it easily

Good Luck